# Error 500 - ¿Por qué me sucede esto y como solucionarlo?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Estuve hablando con mi proveedor de hosting sobre este error y me dijeron que problema de ellos no es. El proyecto es sobre **gestión de stock** y cuando agrego - modifico - elimino proveedores o clientes me funciona re bien. Cuando agrego los productos también. Acá dejo los códigos de ambos archivos que no me tira el **error 500**.

**Código para agregar Proveedor** *add_supplier.php*

```
<?php 
include ('../conexion/bd.php');
require_once "../models/cluster_model.php";

$code = $_POST['code'];
$supplier = $_POST['supplier'];

if($_POST['phone'] == ''){
    $phone = '-';
}else{
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}

if($_POST['mail'] == ''){
    $mail = '-';
}else{
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
}

$obj_cluster = new Cluster_Model();
$retun_supplier = $obj_cluster->PUT_supplier($code, $supplier, $phone, $mail); ?>
```

**Código para agregar Cliente** *add_user_control.php*

```
<?php
include ('../conexion/bd.php');
require_once "../models/cluster_model.php";
$obj_cluster = new Cluster_Model();

$code = $_POST['code'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
  
if($_POST['phone'] == ''){
    $phone = '-';
}else{
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}


$retun_user = $obj_cluster->PUT_user($code, $user, $phone);
?>
```

Pero cuando quiero **dar de baja** algún producto y en otras opciones que tiene mi proyecto de *gestión de stock*, no me deja agregar - modificar - eliminar. En ese momento me tira este error y por eso no entiendo por qué me sucede eso, si en las demás partes me funciona bien.

**El error es este**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código para dar de baja**  *add_sold_control.php*

```
<?php 
include ('../conexion/bd.php');
require_once "../models/cluster_model.php";

$id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
$code = $_POST['codeHFp'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$statu = $_POST['statu'];
$id_last = '';
$stock_current = 0;

if($id_user != '0' && ($amount > 0)){
    
    if(($statu == 1) || ($statu == 2)){
        
        //--> Product - Code
        $obj_Code_P = new Cluster_Model();
        $retun_code_product = $obj_Code_P->Get_code_product($code);

        while($obj_CP = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retun_code_product)){ 
   
            $id_product = $obj_CP['id'];
            
        }   

        //--> PRODUCT <--//   
        $obj_Product = new Cluster_Model();
        $retun_product = $obj_Product->GET_product($id_product);

        while($obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retun_product)){
            $stock_current = $obj['stock'];
        }

        $amount_current = ($stock_current - $amount);

        if($amount_current >= 0){
            
            //--> SOLD <--//
            $obj_PUT_Sold = new Cluster_Model();
            $retun_put_sold = $obj_PUT_Sold->PUT_sold($id_product, $amount);
                                       
            $obj_Post_Sold = new Cluster_Model();
            $retun_post_sold = $obj_Post_Sold->POST_sold();
    
            while($obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retun_sold)){
                $id_last = $obj['id'];
            } 

            if($statu == 1){
                //--> SOLD DETAIL <--//
                $obj_Put_SD = new Cluster_Model();
                $retun_sold_detail = $obj_Put_SD->PUT_sold_detail($id_last, $id_user, $statu);

                $obj_Update_P = new Cluster_Model();
                $retun_update_product = $obj_Update_P->UPDATE_product($id_product, $amount_current);
                return var_dump('True - Facturado.');      
            }
            if($statu == 2){
                //--> SOLD DETAIL <--//
                $obj_Put_Sold_Detail = new Cluster_Model();
                $retun_put_sold_detail = $obj_Put_Sold_Detail->PUT_sold_detail($id_last, $id_user, $statu);

                $obj_Update_Product = new Cluster_Model();
                $retun_up_product = $obj_Update_Product->UPDATE_product($id_product, $amount_current);
                return var_dump('True - Pendiente.');
            }
            
            
            
        }else{
            return var_dump('false');
        }
    }else{
        return var_dump('false');
    }
}else{
    return var_dump('false');
} ?>
```

Comment: El error 500 es un error de servidor, pero se puede generar por múltiples razones. Te sugiero investigar un poco en internet o en con soporte técnico de tu proveedor de hosting.

Comment: Estuve hablando con mi proveedor de hosting y me dijeron que problema de ellos. El proyecto es sobre gestión de stock y cuando agrego, modifico o elimino proveedores, clientes me funciona re bien. Cuando agrego los productos también, pero cuando doy de baja algún producto ahí me tira ese error. Por eso no entiendo por qué sucede eso.

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y comparte el bloque de código que te da error para tratar de reproducir tu escenario. Por otro lado, revisa [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad.

Comment: Y tienes acceso a la consola de tu servidor. Ya que en el navegador el error 500 no se aprecia, pero si ves los log en la terminal, ahí si que se logra apreciar un detalle mas descriptivo del error 500

Answer (score -1):

El error 500 que te indican no es error de servidor sino que de aplicación. En este caso, es el código PHP que tiene problemas.

Si tienes acceso al cPanel o a la configuración de PHP, puedes cambiar las variables de php.ini display_errors a on, o error_reporting a E_ALL. También puedes intentar haciéndolo al principio del código donde está el error, en este caso add_sold_control.php , como `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` o ` ini_set("display_errors", 1); y ahí PHP te explicará con mas detalle cuál es el problema que tienes.

Dentro de cPanel tienes una herramienta del multieditor de php.ini. Ahí lo puedes activar también.

Mucha suerte.
`

Answer (score -1):

Si el error `500` ocurre debido a tu aplicación, podes hacer uso de:

- [`register_shutdown_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

  > Registrar una función para que sea ejecutada al cierre.

  Vamos a usar esta función para suscribir un callback que se ejecutará cada vez que un proceso "termine" (*porque se completo o porque fue interrumpido súbitamente*)
- [`error_get_last()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-get-last.php)

  > Obtener el último error que ocurrió. [...].
  > Devuelve `null` si no ha habido aún un error.

  Vamos a usar esta función para saber si ocurrio un error al momento de "terminar" el proceso.
- [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.debug-backtrace)

  > Genera un rastreo.

  Vamos a usar esta función para obtener la pila de llamadas al momento en que sucedio el evento.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
<?php
// IMPORTANTE!
// Esto debe ser lo primero que hagas en tu archivo PHP (al inicio de todo)

function reportFatalError() {
    $info = error_get_last();
    // Si NO ocurrio un error
    if (!$info) return;

    // Si no es un error FATAL
    if ($info['type'] !== E_ERROR) return;

    // Ejemplo: Imprimimos la información del ULTIMO error
    echo "<b>ER-NRO</b>: " . $info['type'] . "\n<br/>" .
        "<b>ER-MSG</b>: " . $info['message'] . "\n<br/>" .
        "<b>FILE</b>: " . $info['file'] . "\n<br/>" .
        "<b>LINE #</b>: " . $info['line'] . "\n<br/>" .
        "<pre>" . htmlentities(var_export(debug_backtrace(), true)) . "</pre>";
}

// Registramos el callback que se ejecutará al terminar el proceso
register_shutdown_function('reportFatalError');
```

**PD**: Es un ejemplo, queda en vos modificarlo para que funcione según lo necesites.

Comment: Bueno y a donde me aparece el error para verlo? Este código haría en el archivo de add_sold_control.php primero haría eso y después el demás código que puse ahí ?

Comment: @GattiDev, el error aparecería como resultado de la llamada al archivo. Si, este código va primero y después todo tu código